# How to remove touchbar AVPlayer created automatically in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, avplayer, nstouchbar

I'm programming a mac app and I want to support the touchbar. I have a split screen controller and in one of the views is a AVPlayer. The AVPlayer automatically created touchbar buttons for pause and play etc. how can I remove this touchbar that's automatically created? Or is there a way to disable the touchbar for a viewcontroller? I want to add one touchbar for the window in the windowcontroller and at the moment it is overwritten by the touchbar that's automatically crated by AVPlayer.

Comment: Does anybody know how to do this? Like for example disable the touchbar for all viewcontrollers and only display the touchbar of the windowcontroller?

Comment: Try creating your touchbar on the NSWindow itself and add an ".otherItemsProxy" item to the default identifiers and leave plenty of room. This way the AVPlayer touchbar *should* insert itself in the window's one. // I don't think you can *replace* the AVPlayer one with yours, that's why I suggest this solution (not tested, unfortunately, it's just an idea).

Comment: thanks for you idea I'll report back as soon as possible (I'm trying it out today). Do you mean adding ".otherItemsProxy" as the first item in myBar.defaultItemIdentifiers = [.otherItemsProxy, ...] like that?

Comment: Yes but at the end: `[.stuff, .thing, .otherItemsProxy]`. Note that I haven't tested, so maybe it doesn't work. But I would try that, in your case.

Comment: The idea is that the touchBars are prioritized like this: first the AppDelegate, then the NSWindow, then the NSView, then the subviews, etc. So if you have a touchBar with a proxy at the window level, then the items at the view level should insert themselves where the .otherItemsProxy is. At least that's what I understand from the documentation and WWDC videos... :)

Comment: Your solution worked thank you very much! 
That said I hope Apple adds a solution to remove touchbar object for certain viewcontrollers :)

Comment: Great news! I've made a proper answer with this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating your touchbar on the NSWindow itself and add an `.otherItemsProxy` item to the default identifiers:

```
[.stuff, .thing, .otherItemsProxy]
```

This way the AVPlayer touchbar should insert itself in the window's one (I don't think you can replace the AVPlayer one with yours).

The idea is that the touchBars are prioritized like this: first the AppDelegate, then the NSWindow, then the NSView, then the subviews, etc.

So if you have a touchBar with a proxy at the window level, then the items at the view level should insert themselves where the `.otherItemsProxy` is.